# Javascript - regex with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have data attribute like this:

```
data-tags="chaos board nordic viking warriors display ship dock warhammer fantasy"
```

And JS function which is doing the basic filtering of the containers base on tags:

```
var inputFilter = $('#input-filter');
    inputFilter.on('keyup', function() {

        var
            $this  = $(this),
            search = $this.val().toLowerCase();

            if(search.length > 2){
                $('.gallery').hide();
                $("a[data-tags*=" + search + "]").show();
            }

            if(search == ''){
                $('.gallery').show();
            }

    });
```

At the moment this is working for one work only. When I try to search for two or more tags, I get 0 results. How can I make it work?
[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/911hx0bd/1/)

Comment: My input is regular text input box.

Comment: no what are you typing into it?

Comment: Any of the tags from the **data-tags**. For example, I want to search for chaos and viking and get the result.

Comment: you have to split that string.

Answer (score 0):

It works for only one match because you're supplying a literal string, for example `"chaos warriors"`, which is then passed to the attribute-value selector searching for that exact string (`"chaos warriors"`), not for an element containing both of those individual strings (`"chaos"` *and* `"warriors"`).

To search for both those strings individually, I'd suggest (though haven't tried):

```
inputFilter.on('keyup', function() {

    var
        $this  = $(this),
        search = $this.val().toLowerCase(),
        // finding each of the words that are entered:
        words = search.split(/\s+/),
        // declaring the variable for later use:
        data;

        $('.gallery').hide();
        // selecting all <a> elements with a "data-tags" attribute,
        // then filtering that collection:
        $('a[data-tags]').filter(function(){
            // splitting the data-tags attribute to an array of words:
            data = this.dataset.tags.split(/\s+/);

            // looking to see if any of the words (from the value)
            // are present in the array formed from the data-tags
            // attribute, using Array.prototype.some() to iterate
            // over the given array, returning a Boolean true or false:
            return words.some(function (word) {
                data.indexOf(word) > -1;
            });
        }).show();

});
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).
  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: It doesn't work :/. When I try to search, everything becomes hidden.

Comment: Can you put together a minimal ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) demo to help us experiment? Bear in mind that `Array.prototype.some()` may not be supported by your browser, though. Are there any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: And as soon as you stop using my code that demonstration becomes immediately pointless. Also, it's unnecessarily large. The key is to create a *minimal* demo that reproduces your original problem. Strip out every single piece of HTML, CSS and JavaScript that is not *essential* to reproducing the problem, and then post *that* code. Here, in your question (consider also creating a "[Stack Snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)" in your question) and a live demo elsewhere, for example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).